# Increased Evasion Rating - On gear: Does it work for every item?

Tags: path-of-exile

Having **% Increased Evasion Rating** on a piece of gear, will it increase the Evasion Rating of my whole character or only of that piece?

- Example Item: http://pathofexile.gamepedia.com/Ondar%27s_Flight

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That particular modifier is a local modifier, meaning it only affects the item in question.  Global modifiers almost never appear on items that have the property being modified.

Mark explains it [here](http://www.pathofexile.com/forum/view-thread/84366), but basically if the item can have the property being modified, the modifier is local.  If you get +100% evasion on a piece of armor, it's local (armor only).  If you get +100% evasion on a ring, which has no base evasion because it's a ring, it has to be a global modifier.

TL:DR; Assume it is a local modifier, unless it makes no sense, then it has to be a global one.

Comment: If that armor had no Evasion Rating, would "+100% evasion" then be a global modifier? Or was the base evasion an invisble: 0 making it a local modifier as explained. From the Link posted "here" I think It is still local, but i'm not sure.

Comment: For this example, the armor would have a base 0 evasion, local modifier.  In the game itself, the evasion modifiers wouldn't be valid for a non evasion piece of armor, so it wouldn't come up.